# Goofy Unicode problem: mï ¿ ½

Tags: unicode, encoding

I have some text coming into a database that apparently has some sort of Unicode issue. the literal text coming in is "5 mï ¿ ½ in area", which appears to be some sort of unit of measure, but I can't sort out what the meaning is in context. Searching Google shows many similar results, so this is apparently a common set of symbols.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like an encoding mishap somewhere between someone's keyboard and your database. What is the question/problem here, so we can direct the answers appropriately?

Comment: The question is: this looks like a common enough encoding issue that I hoped somoeone would know what the *intended* characters are. I don't have an original document, just a botched database entry from another source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the Unicode replacement character, 0xFFFD (`�`); see also [How to replace ï¿½ in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488866/how-to-replace-i-in-a-string)

So I guess the text used to be `5m² in area`, and the `²` was garbled into `�` before it arrived in your database.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably supposed to be `²` to indicate "meters squared". But you have an encoding problem clearly. I don't know what the problem is because you didn't paste any code or indicate any details for context.