# How to remove "ï¿½" from php string?

Tags: php, string, utf-8, byte-order-mark

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to replace ï¿½ in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488866/how-to-replace-i-in-a-string)

I am reading data from an XML sheet coming out of a database. In the raw output I am coming accross this character "ï¿½" which is the UTF-8 string meaning "�". Doing a simple search and remove with str_replace does not do the trick when searching for "�" or "ï¿½". Is there any other way to remove this character from a string?

UPDATE:

For reference this is the function that is cleaning up strings for me.

```
    function db_utf8_convert($str)
{
    $convmap = array(0x80, 0x10ffff, 0, 0xffffff);
    return preg_replace('/\x{EF}\x{BF}\x{BD}/u', '', mb_encode_numericentity($str, $convmap, "UTF-8"));
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=remove+bom+%5Bphp%5D&submit=search

Comment: 1st result is a SO question, answered: https://www.google.com/search?q=ï¿½  Not sure if that helps or not.

Comment: tried that with a php equivalent statement before asking this, didn't work.

Comment: That's the UTF-8 BOM. The � means invalid character. If you used a parser then you'd not have this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
$str = 'UTF-8 string meaning "ï¿½"';
echo preg_replace('/\x{EF}\x{BF}\x{BD}/u', '', iconv(mb_detect_encoding($str), 'UTF-8', $str));
```

**Output:** `UTF-8 string meaning ""`

Comment: I had high hopes for this but it sadly is not working for me.

Comment: @jlane09 If my first answer was not working it is due to the fact your server is using an encoding other than UTF-8, so I updated my answer for you.

Comment: Still didnt want to work, I appreciate the continued effort though.

Comment: Yeah I figured it might not, since `mb_detect_encoding()` is very limited! Any reason you didn't set your encoding on your DB and Server to UTF-8? This would prevent a lot of future and current issues.

Comment: The DB I am inserting these strings into is encoded in UTF-16. The DB it is coming out of I am not sure and have no control over. The server it is running on is UTF-8

Comment: You should be using one or the other not both.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something similar to this:

```
<?php
$string = "asd fsa fsaf sf ï¿½ asdfasdfs";

echo preg_replace("/[^\p{Latin} ]/u", "", $string);
```

Check out this script for more character matches:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#script

**EDIT**

I did find, this, people says it works, you could give it a try:

```
<?php
function removeBOM($str=""){
    if(substr($str, 0,3) == pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf)) {
        $str=substr($str, 3);
    }
    return $str;
}
?>
```

Comment: That'll also remove many other characters.

Comment: That is why I added the link, it has more combos in it.

Comment: Indeed, but any of the listed scripts will remove *all* characters that are part of that script, not just these 3.

Comment: If someone could post a preg_match that only removes the BOM that would be spectacular.

Comment: Nope, those little BOM's are still popping up using that function.