# How can I replace a unicode character in java string

Tags: java, unicode

I have an issue in my project that is replacing a unicode character with another unicode character in a Java string.

After searching and trying different codes, I didn't get the solution for that I want to replace a character in Persian to another character in Persian with a different unicode number.

I really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: So you're saying that `String#replace(...)` doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Trying this will solve your issue.

```
str.replaceAll("\\p{Sc}", string_to_replcae);
```

and example can be like below:

```
String str = "For some reason my �double quotes� were lost.";
    str = str.replaceAll("\uFFFD", "\"");
```

this example can be viewed from here : [How to replace ï¿½ in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488866/how-to-replace-i-in-a-string)

follow the link for more unicode expressions. http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html