# >> converted to ï¿½

Tags: java, html, jsp, spring-mvc

One of the application user has reported that they are seeing ï¿½  instartd of >> on their home and other pages. There are about 100 users and only one user has this issue. The user is using IE11. what may be the cause of this issue.

Comment: It's a character encoding issue. Your server is sending data in an encoding other than what your browser expects.

Comment: What's the encoding of your website?

Comment: if this is an encoding issue with the server then it should be with all the users right? and also the code to add this >> is hard coded in jsp.  <span class="separator">
   » </span>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have this on top of your `jsp` files:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
```

If you have that, the problem is with your client's browser which hasn't chosen the proper encoding.

Additionally, you may find useful information in this SO question: [How to replace ï¿½ in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488866/how-to-replace-%C3%AF-%C2%BD-in-a-string)